# Copy variable range of values not formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy a variable range from one book (Book1) to the end of a variable range of the another book (book2). I'm interested only in values of the variable range in the book 1 and this is the problem. So I need to find the last row of values (not formulas). On this forum I found several options but none of them works in my case. Here is what I got (Please see the second part of the code "Copy Detail USHB"-'Select cells to copy):

```
                ''''''Copy Detail by Vendor''''''
'Last cell in column

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long
    Set WS = Worksheets("Detail by Vendor")
    With WS
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row + 1
    End With
    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim vFile As Variant

'Set source workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

'Open the target workbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "Book2.xlsm"
'Set selectedworkbook
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

'Select cells to copy
Sheets("By Vendor").Select
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Copy

'Go back to original workbook you want to paste into
wb.Activate
Sheets("Detail by Vendor").Select

'Paste starting at the last empty row
wb.Worksheets("Detail by Vendor").Range("B" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

                    '''''Copy Detail USHB'''''
'Last cell in column
    Set WS = Worksheets("Detail USHB")
    With WS
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row + 1
    End With
'Activate the target workbook
wb2.Activate

'Select cells to copy
Sheets("Detail USHB").Select
Dim jLastRow As Long
jLastRow = Columns("B").Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastRow).Select
Selection.Copy

'Go back to original workbook you want to paste into
wb.Activate
Sheets("Detail USHB").Select

'Paste starting at the last empty row
wb.Worksheets("Detail USHB").Range("B" & LastCellRowNumber).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why did you tag this `java`? Wouldn't `excel-vba` be more appropriate?

Comment: If all you care about are the values -- don't copy/paste at all. Simply `R.Value = S.Value` where `R` and `S` are appropriately set range variables.

Comment: @JohnColeman this range will vary and the range that I need to merge with will vary. So it's not gonna work in my case

Comment: Ranges can be assigned to variables dynamically. You don't have to set a range variable equal to a fixed range. In any event, having a range variable isn't very important. The main point is to use the `Value` property of a range object to directly transfer values with no need to copy/paste. Something like `Range(expression for target range).Value = Range(expression for source range).Value` works.

Comment: Am I correct in believing that you want your source range to be from the last cell in `wb2.Sheets("Detail USHB").Range("B:B")` which contains a constant, and extending to the last used cell in that column - i.e. one constant and all the formulae below it (or perhaps just all the formulae, without the row containing the constant).  And your question is how to find that cell containing the last constant?

Comment: Or (maybe?) do you want your source range to be all the rows in `wb2.Sheets("Detail USHB").Range("B:B")` starting at (say) row 1 (or 2), and extending to the last cell containing a constant.  Or (perhaps?) do you want to copy the entire `wb2.Sheets("Detail USHB").Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` range?

Comment: @YowE3K sorry I wasn't clear. In the Wb2 on the "Detail USHB" tab there is a range("A2:L" & "LastRow"). That last row will vary and if formulas show blank I need to recognize LastRow as a last row with values not with formulas.

Comment: @YowE3K then I find the end of the range in the wb1 and paste the range from the wb2 at the end

Comment: So you want to do `LastRow = wb2.Worksheets("Detail USHB").Range("B:B").Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row` followed by `wb.Worksheets("Detail USHB").Range("B" & LastCellRowNumber).Resize(LastRow-1,1).Value = wb2.Worksheets("Detail USHB").Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Value` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your comments, I believe you are trying to do the following:

```
    '...

    '''''Copy Detail USHB'''''
    Dim D As Range
    Dim S As Range
    With wb2.Worksheets("Detail USHB")
        'Locate the last non-blank value in source range
        LastRow = .Range("B:B").Find(What:="*", _
                                     LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        'Set range
        Set S = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
    End With 
    With wb.Worksheets("Detail USHB")
        'Find last used cell in destination range
        Set D = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        'Offset to next row, and resize appropriately
        Set D = D.Offset(1, 0).Resize(LastRow - 1, 1)
    End With
    'Copy values
    D.Value = S.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: @johncoleman - I changed `R.Value = S.Value` to `D.Value = S.Value` (just so that I couldn't be accused of plagiarism ;) )